# Linux - create an additional directory when adding a new user

Tags: linux

is it possible to create an additional directory when creating a user in linux?

Lets say i add a new user named `suzi`. When I do that, I want to create a home directory as usual under `/home/suzi` and in addition I would like to create another directory under `/work/suzi/` which she owns and she could create her work stuff in.

People browsing the /work directory should only be able to access their own stuff ofc under `/work/$USER`

Comment: Did you get it to work yet?

Answer (score 4):

`man adduser`:

> If the file /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local exists, it will be executed
>   after the user account has been set up in order to do any local setup.
>   The arguments passed to adduser.local are:
>          username uid gid home-directory
>          The environment variable VERBOSE is set according to the following rule:
>
> 0 if --quiet is specified
>
> 1 if neither --quiet nor --debug is specified
>
> 2 if --debug is specified
>
> (The same applies to the variable DEBUG, but DEBUG is deprecated and will be removed in a later version of adduser.)

This should be exactly what you want. (If you are on a Debian distro at least)

Edit: or if it's OK to add the directory in `/home/username/work`or whatever, you can use `SKEL`:

> adduser will copy files from SKEL into the home directory and prompt
>   for finger (gecos) information and a password.  The gecos may also be
>   set with the --gecos  option.   With  the  --disabled-login  option, 
>   the
>          account will be created but will be disabled until a password is set. The --disabled-password option will not set a password, but
>   login is still possible (for example with SSH RSA keys).